# Error running pwntools on Ubuntu 18

Tags: 18.04

I'm on Ubuntu 18 with 64b.

To install [pwntools](https://github.com/Gallopsled/pwntools), I've run:

```
$ sudo apt install python3 python3-pip python3-dev git libssl-dev libffi-dev build-essential
$ sudo python3 -m pip install pwntools
```

When I run `pwn`, it gives me the following error(s):

```
$ pwn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pwn", line 5, in <module>
    from pwnlib.commandline.main import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pwnlib/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    importlib.import_module('.%s' % module, 'pwnlib')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pwnlib/args.py", line 61, in <module>
    from pwnlib import term
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pwnlib/term/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pwnlib.term import completer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pwnlib/term/completer.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pwnlib.term import readline
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pwnlib/term/readline.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pwnlib.term import term
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pwnlib/term/term.py", line 167
    def goto((r, c)):
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How should I fix this to run pwntools?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: run

```
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/Gallopsled/pwntools.git@dev3
```

The pip version of pwntools is not up to date, I currently see version 3.12.2 in pip. This old version does not work properly with python3.

The installation instructions suggests installing directly from the git repo: https://github.com/Gallopsled/pwntools/#installation

The fix was done in this commit:
https://github.com/Gallopsled/pwntools/commit/6c794022d50fcb5c9eeafec3cfc5bdf7728f8a5e

I had the same issue, and this question page was the first Google result. Hope it helps someone! :)

Comment: Even if this link may solve the issue, Link-only answers aren't recommended, due to the risk of seeing these ones die, so could you gather important steps from these links?

Comment: @damadam I agree, thanks for making me a better contributor.

However, in this case the problem is that the `pip` version of `pwntools` is outdated. The solution is to install `pwntools` from source, and the links are to the source.

I have gathered the single relevant instruction; the command line to install from source with `pip`. This wont work if the links die. (They all point to the same github repository.)

I'm not sure it would help to gather the source code here. ;)